# Failed when hot standby parameter is changed

Tags: postgresql

I have configured primary / standby in version 10. If I change the hot_standby parameter to off on the standby then I can no longer connect and there is this error in log: FATAL log: the database system is starting up.
I don't understand this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hot standby" is the database feature that allows you to connect to a recovering server (like a standby). If you disable that feature, it is no surprise if you can no longer connect to the standby.

The error message is the normal message you get from a recovering server that does not allow connections.

The FATAL message is not as bad as it seems. "Fatal" indicates an error message that terminates a database session. It is the message you get if you try to connect to a database that is not yet ready for connections.